# Comparing DateTime Not Working

Tags: php, datetime, compare

I created two datetime objects where $date1 = 09/02/2013 and $date2 = 03/02/2014

When I run the following code:

```
if ($date2 < $date1)
{
  echo "hi";
}
```

for some reason it echos "hi" although $date2 is clearly greater than $date1. How am i supposed to compare these two dates? Please help!

Comment: use `if(strototime($date2) < strtotime($date1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like below with function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
if (strtotime($date2 ) < strtotime($date1))
{
 echo "hi";
}
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @nshah, welcome. Will you please accept my answer so if anybody has some issue in future so they can utilize our thread.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime ('2013-12-25');
$date2 = new DateTime ('2014-11-24');
if ($date1 > $date2) {
echo ('date1 is greater than date2');
}
else {
echo ('date2 is greater than date1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That could work in JavaScript, but in PHP it will not :P

However, you could calculate an interval between dates.

```
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
if ($interval->invert){ //1 if negative and 0 if positive
  // $date2 has a bigger time value
} else {
  // $date1 has a bigger time value
}
```